# Android Studio app won't change its default icon when run on device

Tags: android, android-studio, icons

I've created a simple icon using Image Asset (only changing the background color and the object using clip art) but it won't show on device. I've checked all the places where I store the icon (mipmap, android manifest) and they all show the icon I want. The icon type is adaptive and legacy and I checked the mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder it looks alright.

I've also tried on a new project changing the icon and it worked, but I want to change the icon of the current project I'm working on.

What could be the problem??

[mipmap-anydpi-v26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP2JE.png)

[android manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbRoL.png)

[ic_launcher.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRA6x.png)

Comment: your testing device api level?

Comment: I use Android 8.0 - API level 26

Comment: compare compile nd target sdk version